# Mongodb, can i trigger secondary replication only at the given time or manually?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, master-slave, replicaset

I'm not a mongodb expert, so I'm a little unsure about server setup now.

I have a single instance running mongo3.0.2 with wiredtiger, accepting both read and write ops. It collects logs from client, so write load is decent. Once a day I want to process this logs and calculate some metrics using aggregation framework, data set to process is something like all logs from last month and all calculation takes about 5-6 hours. 
I'm thinking about splitting write and read to avoid locks on my collections (server continues to write logs while i'm reading, newly written logs may match my queries, but i can skip them, because i don't need 100% accuracy).

In other words, i want to make a setup with a secondary for read, where replication is not performing continuously, but starts in a configured time or better is triggered before all read operations are started.

I'm making all my processing from node.js so one option i see here is to export data created in some period like [yesterday, today] and import it to read instance by myself and make calculations after import is done. I was looking on replica set and master/slave replication as possible setups but i didn't get how to config it to achieve the described scenario. 
So maybe i wrong and miss something here? Are there any other options to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe i will try to add more facts, it's not very easy to make it brief, because i have about 15 different aggregations... But, my question is not really about them, i edited a subject a little. My main question is: how can i get a setup where replication on the secondary is not performing continuously, but starts in a configured time or better is triggered before all read operations are started.

Comment: You can't, you shouldn't and I wouldn't help ;) as said before, you might want to to use a secondary in the first place.

Comment: When you only start replication before you do the reports, you won't know how long it takes until it is synchronized. Why not let replication run constantly? The additional load on the master is negligible *and* you gain the additional perk of automatic failover in case the primary goes down unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea of using a replica-set is flawed for several reasons.

First, a replica-set always replicates the whole mongod instance. You can't enable it for individual collections, and certainly not only for specific documents of a collection.

Second, deactivating replication and enabling it before you start your report generation is not a good idea either. When you enable replication, the new slave will not be immediately up-to-date. It will take a while until it has processed the changes since its last contact with the master. There is no way to tell how long this will take (you can check how far a secondary is behind the primary using [`rs.status()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.status/#rs.status) and comparing the secondaries `optimeDate` with its `lastHeartbeat` date).

But when you want to perform data-mining on a subset of your documents selected by timespan, there is another solution.

Transfer the documents you want to analyze to a new collection. You can do this with an aggregation pipeline consisting only of a $match which matches the documents from the last month followed by an [$out](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/). The out-operator specifies that the results of the aggregation are not sent to the application/shell, but instead written to a new collection (which is automatically emptied before this happens). You can then perform your reporting on the new collection without locking the actual one. It also has the advantage that you are now operating on a much smaller collection, so queries will be faster, especially those which can't use indexes. Also, your data won't change between your aggregations, so your reports won't have any inconsistencies between them due to data changing between them.

When you are certain that you will need a second server for report generation, you can still use replication and perform the aggregation on the secondary. However, I would really recommend you to [build a proper replica-set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/) (consisting of primary, secondary and an [arbiter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-replica-set-arbiter/)) and leave replication active at all times. Not only will that make sure that your data isn't outdated when you generate your reports, it also gives you the important benefit of automatic failover should your primary go down for some reason.

Comment: You're totally right here with a point that replication is not what i need, when i perform mining, and i understand it, so my suggestion was to transfer documents to new mongodb instance. Transfering it to new collection sounds interesting, thanks for this point. I think i will end up with building a "proper" replica set and i will think about transfering data to a temporary collection before processing - all my aggregations start from {$match: {date: {$gte: begin, $lte: end}}} anyway.